# Putting HTML in a Wordpress PHP call

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm looking to add an image in the header right text div instead of calling for the text from the theme. I want to do this manually, but can't figure out the proper syntax. Here is the code:

```
echo '<div class="logo-right-text">';
                echo do_shortcode( __(get_option(THEME_SHORT_NAME . '_logo_right_text'), 'gdl_front_end') );
                echo '</div>';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to add an image and keep the header right text?

Comment: I want the image in the header right text div. Not necessarily keep the text.

Comment: if you want to do this manually why don't you just you an img tag?

Comment: Where would I add the image tag within that code?

Comment: Do you need that shortcode to run? it's really hard to tell whats going on on the second line since there is a ton of code that's calling out to. If you don't care if that shortcode runs I can post an answer for you.

Comment: Yeah, by all means. I don't need the shortcode. I just need an image to appear in the div. Currently I cannot add HTML to the shortcode...only text, hence the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You upload image  to images directory into theme current:

```
echo '<div class="logo-right-text">';
echo '<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Image_name.png" border="0"></a>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much! However, when I try to link the images it does not have a hover nor click to another page. Not sure if I should ask here or another question all together?

Comment: let me know if you have any question

Comment: change link for image: echo '<a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Image_name.png" border="0"></a>';

Comment: Did that, but it won't allow for a click. Check the social links here: http://tinyurl.com/q6j8cro

Comment: Try this: add css to file style.css .logo-right-text a{
    display: block;
}

Comment: It was the size of the logo that was making it an issue. Had to max it out at 600 px and then center it.

Comment: You can resize the logo and using CSS to align center it